# What is the max voltage 74HC4067 IC can withstand on output side when non of the channels are selected?

Tags: analog, high-voltage, multiplexer

I have [74HC4067](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4067.pdf) (ESD 200 V)

Vcc 3.3V
Switching voltage 3.3V
Input voltage 3.3V

In my application when non of channels are selected, 16 output pins will have connection to 100V 9mA source one pin at a time ,

What is the leakage current to ground if 100V is applied on output side?
will ic damage due to this 100V?

Comment: Yes. You are clamped by Vcc.

Comment: @winny I would expect the outputs to be clamped to GND and VCC, but the data sheet only says inputs are clamped (so you can interface to higher voltage logic with a series resistor). I see no abs max spec for output pin clamp current, no diagrams of clamp diodes, and the only bit in abs max saying output pins should stay between GND and VCC is in a note about leakage current and maximum switch differential voltage. So I'm unable to give a clear 'the outputs are clamped' assertion from the data sheet alone, much though I'd like to.

Comment: @Neil_UK NXP usually have good and clear datasheets, but this one isn't.

Comment: I am not sticking into NXP brand 74HC4067, any other brand is okay like texas instruments etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting values for clamped voltage is VCC+0.5V and GND-0.5V, when current is limited to 20mA. The supply pins cannot take more than 50mA of clamping current though.

Recommended operating conditions say that voltages should be within VCC and GND.

Feeding 9mA to input gets clamped to VCC, so your 3V3 supply must allow for this so that the extra 9mA is consumed somewhere so that the supply does not go above 3.3V, as many regulators cannot sink current, only source it.

Note that the mux switch pins are analog so they are both inputs and outputs at the same time, so the assignment is up to the user which pins are inputs and outputs, the mux does not care. Some implementations may have different limits for the common terminal, so read the datasheet carefully.

I don't recommend feeding 9mA from 100V into the mux, it should be handled externally if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in the [Nexperia datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4067.pdf) that you link to it is not mentioned in the **Limiting values** (usually called Maximum ratings) that the voltage on **any** of the pins **cannot exceed the supply voltages** (Vcc and ground) by more than ~0.4 V.

Some manufacturers have an "overall" datasheet describing the electrical characteristics and maximum ratings of a complete family of (logic) chips in more detail. I cannot find such a datasheet at this moment.

The reason why (as mentioned in the comments) the outputs will be clamped (to about Vcc + 0.6 V) when you apply 100 V to them is the **ESD protection circuit**. The datasheet does mention **input clamping current** (max 25 mA) and that is the maximum current that is allowed to flow through the ESD diodes. This schematic shows how these diodes are connected inside the chip:

[image]

I got that image from [this document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slya014a/slya014a.pdf) parts of which might be interesting for you to read.

Your 4067 chip, like basically all CMOS chips have ESD diodes connected to all their signal pins. Imagine what will happen if you apply 100 V (even if it is limited to 9 mA) to the pin marked "Output". Then D3 will conduct and try to pull Vcc to 100 V as well!

If that would happen then you could potentially damage **everything connected to Vcc**.

**If** there as a voltage clamp between Vcc and ground and you're absolutely sure that never more than 25 mA will flow (even a small capacitor charged to 100 V will make more current flow!) then what you propose could work and might not damage anything **but** it's like **playing with fire**, it is a very bad design practice.

If you need to switch something which can handle 100 V then you must use a transistor for example a MOSFET. The 4000 series CMOS logic chips are simply not designed for direct use with high voltages.

Also of interest might be this: [HCMOS Design Considerations](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scla007a/scla007a.pdf) document.